# How electronic circuit works?

Tags: current, basic

If current flows through phase and is fed to the desired circuit and electrons after traveling through the circuit, and comes out through neutral and then to ground...then what makes the circuit work if electrons come out of the circuit?

Comment: That's because of the [magic smoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke).

Answer (score 4):

> what make circuit work if electrons comes out of circuit

The other end of the circuit sucking the electrons back in again.

For this kind of circuit question I find it is best to think of it like rain.

[image]

The sun is the generator, power station, battery, or whatever your energy source might be.  The water is the electrons in the circuit.

The sun warms the water, turns it to vapour, and feeds it into the air. It then falls through the air as rain back to the ground. It then trickles through the streams and rivers to the lakes and the seas, where it is then evaporated all over again.

Similar happens with an electronic circuit.  The power source pushes the electrons into the circuit (air). They flow through the circuit (rain) to ground (rivers), where it then flows back to the power source (lakes and seas). The power source then starts the cycle all over again.

Of course, like all analogies, this is completely wrong.

Comment: *"Of course, like all analogies, this is completely wrong"* [Wittgenstein's Ladder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children) is a valid technique in this case. +1

Comment: AKA "Lies To Children" as Terry Pratchett called it.

Comment: God rest his soul. A fine author of fiction, just like you LOL +1

Comment: I wonder which god has his soul?  My money's on Offler.

Answer (score 0):

The electrons come out of the phase (are pushed out), go through the circuit, to the neutral, but don't go to the ground. They go back to the secondary of a transformer that pushed them out in the first place.

They would go through the ground only if it was part of the circuit.

But then the transformer stops pushing the electrons out, and starts sucking them in, reversing the direction of the electron flow.

100 or 120 times per second depending where in the world you are.

Ground is sometimes used as part of a circuit. In that case the electrons will enter the
ground, go through it, then exit to complete the path to the source.